# Converting Velocity ECEF to NED or LLA/Geodetic

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, java, cartesian, ecef

I'm able to get a correct **position** from ECEF to Geodetic to NED with a relative footpoint and can verify using online conversion tools:

- https://www.oc.nps.edu/oc2902w/coord/llhxyz.htm
- https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/NCAT/
- https://tool-online.com/en/coordinate-converter.php

But it doesn't make mention in regards to calculating velocity, I've read through

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#From_ECEF_to_ENU
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_tangent_plane_coordinates

Neither the position calculation or the rotation matrix from wikipedia seem to convert my cartesian velocities correctly, I have an expected position and velocity cartesian data set to compare with.

**My question is, how do I convert my ECEF velocity to NED?**

---

Aside: Converting between NED and ENU are straight forward and I have something to convert NED/ENU to/from Geodetic/LLA (Most sources also use varying terms and names for reference frames, my scenario has origin from a mobile point that gets data regarding a moving object, the moving object is reported as NED and/or ECEF from a 3rd party reporting device. The NED coordinate is the expected value, I need to convert the ECEF to match 'close enough' as the NED value is limited to lower earth altitudes and this update is expected to include tracking of something like the moon ~384472.3km)

I've tagged Java, but any algorithm format that's legible should work.